# Adding DB_HOST environment varibale to Ubuntu VM in provision.sh

Tags: linux, environment-variables, virtual-machine, vagrant-provision

This is the code I have currently in my provision.sh file for vagrant to run when setting up my VM: (I do have other code before this to install packages etc, it is all working, it's just that this environment variable is not being created and set)

```
#Add DB_HOST env variable
export DB_HOST=192.168.10.150:27017/posts
echo "DB_HOST=192.168.10.150:27017/posts" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Is there something massively wrong with this? Or is there some other method that I have to use?

Comment: __Where__ do you want to have the environment variable set? To have the variable set inside an interactive Bash shell you can set the variable in `.bashrc`. It will not affect other shells. It will not affect non-shells.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm not entirely sure what your asking, but I want to be able to do the command `env` and then see that DB_HOST has been set within the variables that are printed. Or do the command `printenv DB_HOST` and then the value is returned (`192.168.10.150:27017/posts`)

Comment: Each process in Linux is created by `fork()` and then `execve()` - each process "comes" from somewhere and has a parent process. `to do the command env` What process will run `env`? Bash shell? Dash shell? Zsh shell? Systemd service? Graphical manager autostart .desktop runner? If you do `env -i env`, then second `env` will _always_ print nothing, there is no way to affect it. To set environment variable for _all login sessions_ you can set it in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Would I just have to `echo` the string into the `/etc/environment` file in the provision file? Similar to what I've done already, just within the relevant file.

Comment: `Would I just have to echo` Yes. And relogin.

Comment: Interestingly, I wasn't able to `echo` to the etc/environment file. I looked it up and its something to do with the way that sudo wraps commands, and you need to sudo the opening of the file. This is how I got it to work > `echo "DB_HOST=mongodb://192.168.10.150:27017/posts" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to KamilCuk for helping me with this.

He told me to `echo` into the `/etc/environment` file, and add the DB_HOST env variable in there to make it persistent.

I did have some issues doing this and here is the command I used to make it work > `echo "DB_HOST=[db-ip]" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`

So, `echo` the variable name and its value, then pipe that into a `tee` command, which basically just opens a file and allows write access (I think). You need to do it in this way because you need root user permissions to open and write to the `/etc/environment` file, and you don't need to use sudo in order to complete the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

To let a linux programm start with a special set of environment variables you can use: `env -i ...`

Example for a shell function that provides a special environment for the Lua interpreter...

```
lua () 
{ 
    ( env -i LANG='de_DE.UTF-8' TERM='xterm-256color' LUA_PATH='./lua/?.lua' LUA_CPATH='./lua/?.so' /usr/local/bin/lua "${@}" )
}
```

...give me the environment what i want.
This example use full path to Lua executable and need therefore no `PATH` variable.

The function is placed in `.bashrc` (user system login) or `.profile` (user remote login) of a normal users home folder.

Impression...

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require('dialog')
dialog: 0x56690120  ./lua/dialog.lua
-- Do special german chars work too?
> _G['ÜüÄäÖöß']='It works!'
> print(_G['ÜüÄäÖöß'])
It works!
-- Environment is also used by child(s) (inherit)...
> os.execute('env')
PWD=/home/knoppix
LINES=54
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
COLUMNS=190
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=0
LUA_CPATH=./lua/?.so
LUA_PATH=./lua/?.lua
_=/usr/bin/env
true    exit    0
```

This is working in multiuser environments without being superuser root first.
Because normal users arent allowed to write something in `/` or `/etc/` that belongs to: `root`